# Sort examples in pandas dataframe by maximum of three columsn

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting, max

```
  home_team_name away_team_name       ev1       ev0       ev2
0       Sassuolo        Udinese  0.213624 -0.152282 -0.306609
1       Cagliari      Sampdoria  0.278430 -0.086284 -0.243369
2      Benevento         Spezia -0.079299 -0.000337  0.078663
3          Parma     Fiorentina  0.570120 -0.078788 -0.364922
4          Lazio       Juventus  0.483111 -0.040047 -0.284971
```

I would like to sort the dataframe above in descending order. I would like to sort the rows by the maximum of the columns ev1, ev0 and ev2. To clarify in row 0 the max is ev1 in row 2 the max is ev2. This value would serve as the value on which to conduct the sort. It is very important that I also know which column was the max in the particular row.

sort_values sort only by one value. Now I could possibly get the max and construct a new column, but like I said I would also like the name of the column that is the max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the max, assign to new column and sort:

```
df['max_val'] = df.filter(like='ev').max(1)
df.sort_values('max_val')
```

If you don't want to modify your data, you can sort the series and use `loc` or use `argsort` and `iloc`

```
max_val = df.filter(like='ev').max(1)

df.loc[max_val.sort_values(ascending=False).index]

# also
# df.iloc[np.argsort(-max_val, axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
  home_team_name away_team_name       ev1       ev0       ev2
3          Parma     Fiorentina  0.570120 -0.078788 -0.364922
4          Lazio       Juventus  0.483111 -0.040047 -0.284971
1       Cagliari      Sampdoria  0.278430 -0.086284 -0.243369
0       Sassuolo        Udinese  0.213624 -0.152282 -0.306609
2      Benevento         Spezia -0.079299 -0.000337  0.078663
```

For the column names with max values, use `idxmax`:

```
df['max_col'] = df.filter(like='ev').idxmax(1)
```

Output:

```
  home_team_name away_team_name       ev1       ev0       ev2 max_col
0       Sassuolo        Udinese  0.213624 -0.152282 -0.306609     ev1
1       Cagliari      Sampdoria  0.278430 -0.086284 -0.243369     ev1
2      Benevento         Spezia -0.079299 -0.000337  0.078663     ev2
3          Parma     Fiorentina  0.570120 -0.078788 -0.364922     ev1
4          Lazio       Juventus  0.483111 -0.040047 -0.284971     ev1
```